# Create a Terminal command to open file with Chrome

Tags: terminal, google-chrome

I want to create command in terminal that would allow me to use

```
chrome index.html
```

and have the the given file open in Google Chrome.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command with the `-a` flag to open a file or location in Chrome:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" index.html
```

This also works with URLs, *i.e.* `open -a "Google Chrome" http://www.apple.com`.

Comment: You can also make it just like in the question using alias:
alias chrome='open -a "Google Chrome"'
chrome index.html

Comment: Note: It also accepts globbing and will open in your current window, so e.g. `open -a "Google Chrome" *.html` opens all the matched `html` files as new tabs in the current Chrome's (active?) window

Answer (score 13):

I found this way more beautiful:

1. Edit `~/.bash_profile` file and add the following line
   `alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"`
2. Save and close the file.
3. Either run `source ~/.bash_profile` or open a new window in Terminal.

You can now open the file, file.html, by running: `chrome file.html` on the command line.

Answer (score 6):

When using this from a script or some automation tool I prefer to alias to the complete binary so I have access to all the command line options, (like `--version` ...)

```
alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
chrome --version
chrome -open index.html
```

Then if you want to have this alias permanently you can add it to your `.bash_profile` manually or using this little snippet:

```
echo "alias chrome=\"/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"\" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I had to specify "shopt -s expand_aliases" in my bash script to use an alias.

Answer (score -1):

From anywhere

```
start chrome path/file.html
```

just type the file name with extension if you are at that folder where file reside and your default browser should be chrome.

```
index.html
```

if chrome is not default Browser for that file

```
start chrome index.html
```

Comment: I get `-bash: start: command not found` when running `start chrome`, and `-bash: index.html: command not found` when entering `index.html`. Is there an addon which needs to be installed to make this work?